# is there a difference between if $str = "" and if empty($str)?

Tags: php, comparison

WIll there be any reason why `if ($str == "")` and `if (empty($str))` don't produce the same output?

Comment: they don't produce output at all. they're conditions.

Comment: @think123 - they do produce output, boolean output.

Comment: yes, but they are put in if statements, so there wouldn't be any direct 'output'. I can understand where you're coming from though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$str == ""` will return TRUE for

- `$str = "";`
- `$str = false;`
- `$str = NULL;`
- `$str = 0;`
- `$str = 0.0;`

`$str == ""` will return FALSE for

- `$str = "0";`
- `$str = array();`

Note: It will also return TRUE for an undefined variable but it is a warning.

On the other hand `empty($str)` will be TRUE for all the cases above (including the undefined variable), with no warning.

As for the reason of this difference, it is because the function `empty` is intended to test for an emtpy variable (of any type, for example an array or a number*) not only an empty string.

*: as you may now PHP is happy with numbers stored in strings, it will just convert the value as needed, for example `echo "1" + 2` gives `3`. And that's why `empty($str)` returns TRUE when `$str = "0"`, not because of it being an empty string (it's not) but because it is an empty number.

For testing if an string is empty, I strongly recomend to use either `$str === ''` or `strlen($str) === 0`.

Answer (score 2):

`$str = "0";`
for example. Refer to [this](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.empty.php) fine doc.

Answer (score 2):

`$str == ""` will be true for all `empty($str)` except the following value of $str:

- `"0"` (0 as a string)
- `array()` (an empty array)

Comment: To spell it out more: THIS ANSWER IS WRONG! Try proving the first sentence.

Comment: Edited the post, Initial answer was an overlook from my part

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If `$str` is equal to `"0"` then `empty($str)` will return `TRUE` while `$str == ""` will return `FALSE`.

See the manual page: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Answer (score 1):

`empty` is the same as `== false` (without raising an error for nonexistent variables). If you refer to the [Type Comparison Tables](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php), you'll see that `"0"` and `array()` will compare differently.